# update a group of users id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a long list of user information (userid, username, password and level)
Now I wish to update a large number of user's level but I don't want to do that by a single command for each of the users. Is there a way to update all of them at once ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function in your `WHERE` statement to include all of the IDs you wish to update.

```
UPDATE users
   SET level=1
 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Or, if everyone shares a common unique value in a column, you can use that instead. For example, if you wanted to update everyone at level 1 to go to level 2:

```
UPDATE users
   SET level=2
 WHERE level=1;
```